# Is myDesign for thread communication acceptable?

Tags: c++, multithreading, qt, communication, signals-slots

I am currently trying to create a good and working `Qt` design for communication between several threads. I have a preference window, which emits different signals up on clicking on apply. For example one for creating the SQL connection and one changing other stuff. I want to change the preferences in a background thread in different classes and after  making the changes they shall emit a result signal. In my preferences window I now want to wait until all signals are received (either with a true or a false result) before I either close the window or print an error message.

I tried to draw my design in the attached picture. Is that the correct way for my purpose? I am currently struggling with the way of waiting for all results. I was thinking of creating some kind of array to save every result and check the array, whether all signals are received. But that sounds pretty ugly... Is there a better method to wait until all signals are received?

Also is it a good idea to make the classes in the background thread as a `singelton`? I only need one instance of the classes and that would make the access to the classes pretty easy since I do not need to drag the pointers to every object, which needs to know the classes.

Also i would like to know, whether it is a good Idea to store a public member in the MySQL Class, which tells me, whether the Database is connected and access it directly out of other threads?

Thank you!

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `QStateMachine` will do exactly what you want: it can transition between states when it receives signals.

The background threads might not need to be based on classes, and no matter what they definitely shouldn't be singletons. Most likely you can give a functor to `QtConcurrent::run`, and emit the signal there.

The logic should be factored out into a separate `QObject`:

```
// https://github.com/KubaO/stackoverflown/tree/master/questions/thread-jobs-39109247
#include <QtWidgets>
#include <QtConcurrent>
#include <functional>

class Controller : public QObject {
    Q_OBJECT
    QStateMachine m_machine{this};
    QState s_init{&m_machine};
    QState s_busy{&m_machine};
    QState s_idle{&m_machine};
    int m_activeTasks = 0;
    void onTaskStarted() {
        ++ m_activeTasks;
        emit taskRunning();
    }
    void onTaskDone() {
        if (--m_activeTasks == 0) emit allTasksDone();
    }
    Q_SIGNAL void taskRunning();
    Q_SIGNAL void allTasksDone();
    Q_SIGNAL void task1Done(int result);
    Q_SIGNAL void task2Done(int result);
public:
    Q_SIGNAL void active();
    Q_SIGNAL void finished();
    Q_SLOT void doTask1() {
        onTaskStarted();
        QtConcurrent::run([this]{
            QThread::sleep(2); // pretend we do some work
            emit task1Done(42);
        });
    }
    Q_SLOT void doTask2() {
        onTaskStarted();
        QtConcurrent::run([this]{
            QThread::sleep(5); // pretend we do some work
            emit task2Done(44);
        });
    }
    Controller(QObject * parent = nullptr) :
        QObject{parent}
    {
        // This describes the state machine
        s_init.addTransition(this, &Controller::taskRunning, &s_busy);
        s_idle.addTransition(this, &Controller::taskRunning, &s_busy);
        s_busy.addTransition(this, &Controller::allTasksDone, &s_idle);
        m_machine.setInitialState(&s_init);
        m_machine.start();
        //
        connect(this, &Controller::task1Done, this, [this](int result){
            onTaskDone();
            qDebug() << "task 1 is done with result" << result;
        });
        connect(this, &Controller::task2Done, this, [this](int result){
            onTaskDone();
            qDebug() << "task 2 is done with result" << result;
        });
        connect(&s_busy, &QState::entered, this, &Controller::active);
        connect(&s_idle, &QState::entered, this, &Controller::finished);
    }
};

Q_GLOBAL_STATIC(QStringListModel, model)
int main(int argc, char ** argv) {
    using Q = QObject;
    QApplication app{argc, argv};
    Controller ctl;
    QWidget w;
    QFormLayout layout{&w};
    QPushButton start1{"Start Task 1"};
    QPushButton start2{"Start Task 2"};
    QListView log;
    layout.addRow(&start1);
    layout.addRow(&start2);
    layout.addRow(&log);
    Q::connect(&start1, &QPushButton::clicked, &ctl, &Controller::doTask1);
    Q::connect(&start2, &QPushButton::clicked, &ctl, &Controller::doTask2);
    Q::connect(&ctl, &Controller::active, []{ qDebug() << "Active"; });
    Q::connect(&ctl, &Controller::finished, []{ qDebug() << "Finished"; });

    log.setModel(model);
    qInstallMessageHandler(+[](QtMsgType, const QMessageLogContext &, const QString & msg){
        auto row = model->rowCount();
        model->insertRow(row);
        model->setData(model->index(row), msg);
    });
    w.show();
    return app.exec();
}
#include "main.moc"
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I do not know for now, whether `QtConcurrent::run` is an option for me, I cannot tell that for now, but I think i understand the concept.  What is the problem with singletons in that case? Otherwise i would need every class, which needs to communicate with that thread to know the pointer to that object, which sounds pretty intricate...

Comment: As for `QStateMachine` I do not quite get the concept, do you may have a small example? As I understand I have to create a state for every possible signal and the belonging result code for every of my classes. I would initialize them with a state telling me that they are not processed yet. In my waiting procedure I will check every state continuosly until every state has a valid state. Did I understood that correctly?

Comment: First of all, you assume that there is *the* thread. You probably don't need to concern yourself with it. Let the `QThreadPool` manage the threads in the most efficient manner, and submit work to them using `QtConcurrent::run`. The controller - the business logic - can be a single `QObject` that submits work to be done concurrently and acts on the results, see the edit.

Comment: The state machine concept is very important in any software development, you should familiarize yourself with it. You may or may not need create a state for every signal, it really depends on what you're trying to do.

Comment: "In my waiting procedure I will check every state continuosly until every state has a valid state." Forget about waiting for anything. In modern asynchronous code, there's no waiting. Ever. The event loop waits. You get informed when things happen - your code runs in reaction to things happening.

Comment: A state machine could keep track of the number of active operations and indicate when they are all done. In principle you need only two states: `busy` and `idle`, and a counter that you increment every time a job gets submitted, and decremented every time a job is done. A guarded transition decrements the counter and only goes back to `idle` state when the counter hits zero.

Comment: Thank you! I will try to overthink my design and implement your suggestions!